# IRT in R: Does anyone know of an IRT item calibration function that can cope with NA's?

Tags: r, psychometrics, item-response-theory

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
test.takers item1   item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10 item11 item12 item13 item14 item16 item17 item18 total_score
tt1             1       1     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     NA      1      1     NA      1      1      1      1          12
tt2             0       1     0     0     0     0     0    NA     1      1     NA      0      1      0     NA      1      0           6
tt3             1       1     1     1     0     0    NA     1    NA     NA      1      1      1     NA      0     NA      0           8
tt4             1       1     1     0     1    NA     1     1     0      0     NA      1     NA      1      0      0     NA           8
tt5             0       1     1     0     1     1    NA    NA     0      1      1      1     NA      0      0      1      1           9
tt6             0       0     0     1     1     1     1    NA     1      1      1     NA      1      1     NA      0      0           9
tt7             1       0     0     1     1     1     1     1    NA      0      1      1      1      0      1      1     NA          11
```

The dataset consists of 3000 test takers with their responses on an ability test. Not all test takers could respond on all 18 items. So some test takers saw only 10 items, others only 12, etc. The result is a data frame with a lot of NA's. Now I want to calibrate the item parameters using a 2pl irt model. And after that I want to calibrate test taker abilities on the same dataset. The problem I face is that I can't find an R package that can handle calibration on a data frame with missing data.

Does anyone know of an R package or R function that could do the job for me or knows how to deal with this problem in some other genious way?

Comment: The question reminds me of something I once read, but I haven't actually applied it so I can't give any further info, and don't know if it is helpful in your case:

"Missing data can be handled in the smacof package by passing the weightmat argument to the smacofIndDiff function."

Comment: I might be missing something in your question, but both the `ltm` and `mirt` packages can handle missing data just fine for 2PL models. Have you tried either of those packages? Also, the reason I didn't post this response as an answer is that I'm worried about how the missingness occurred. Can the NA's be assumed to be MCAR or MAR?

Comment: thank you for your response. I examined the ltm package once again and it does seem to be capabel to deal with the problem! Because I focused on irtoys package first (and i initially ran into errors when using ltm) I wrongly concluded calibration wasn't possible with my dataset. The NA's can be assumed to be MCAR.

Comment: Okay great. I'll add an example of how this is done with both packages then as the answer

Comment: Great stuff to examine.  My final goal is to obtain test taker abilities in this dataset. @Philchalmers, do you think it's a proper way to obtain test taker abilities this way, and using your solution as step 1?

Comment: Yes I think so, since all of the estimates will be based on the available response pattern of each participant, while the NA's will contribute no extra information to the latent score. This approach will also tell you the relative error in the responses that contain missing data by just calling `fscores(mirtmod)` (or equivalently `factor.scores(ltmmod)`) and observing standard error values. You may want to try other estimators (e.g., ML, MAP, etc) but they will all have the properties I mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I stated in the comments above, missing data can be handled by either the `ltm` or `mirt` package when the data is MCAR. Here is an example of how to use both on a dataset with missing values:

```
> library(ltm)
> library(mirt
> set.seed(1234)
> dat <- expand.table(LSAT7)
> dat[sample(1:(nrow(dat)*ncol(dat)), 150)] <- NA
> head(dat)
     Item.1 Item.2 Item.3 Item.4 Item.5
[1,]      0      0      0      0      0
[2,]      0      0      0      0      0
[3,]      0      0      0      0      0
[4,]      0      0      0      0      0
[5,]      0      0      0      0      0
[6,]      0      0      0      0     NA
> (ltmmod <- ltm(dat ~ z1))

Call:
ltm(formula = dat ~ z1)

Coefficients:
        Dffclt  Dscrmn
Item.1  -1.891   0.967
Item.2  -0.720   1.147
Item.3  -1.008   1.885
Item.4  -0.671   0.760
Item.5  -2.554   0.729

Log.Lik: -2572.402

> (mirtmod <- mirt(dat, 1))
Iteration: 22, Log-Lik: -2572.402, Max-Change: 0.00010
Call:
mirt(data = dat, model = 1)

Full-information item factor analysis with 1 factors 
Converged in 22 iterations with 41 quadrature. 
Log-likelihood = -2572.402
AIC = 5164.805; AICc = 5165.027
BIC = 5213.882; SABIC = 5182.122
> coef(mirtmod)
$Item.1
       a1     d g u
par 0.967 1.829 0 1

$Item.2
       a1     d g u
par 1.148 0.826 0 1

$Item.3
       a1     d g u
par 1.886 1.902 0 1

$Item.4
      a1    d g u
par 0.76 0.51 0 1

$Item.5
       a1     d g u
par 0.729 1.863 0 1

$GroupPars
    MEAN_1 COV_11
par      0      1
```

It's also possible to impute missing values given a good estimate of $\theta$ for obtaining things like model and item fit statistics (should do this several times if the amount of missingness is non-trivial, and it's even better to jitter the $\hat{\theta}$ values as a function of the respective $SE_{\hat{\theta}}$ values for more reasonable imputation results).

```
> Theta <- fscores(mirtmod, full.scores = TRUE, scores.only = TRUE)
> fulldat <- imputeMissing(mirtmod, Theta)
> head(fulldat)
  Item.1 Item.2 Item.3 Item.4 Item.5
1      0      0      0      0      0
2      0      0      0      0      0
3      0      0      0      0      0
4      0      0      0      0      0
5      0      0      0      0      0
6      0      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: If I try to estimate abilities using the samen data set it says: Error in solve.default(object$hessian) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number.  Any ideas about how to pass this problem?

Comment: Which package are you using, mirt or ltm?

Comment: I am using ltm.

Comment: The above example seemed to work okay for me. Not sure why you ran into problems with `ltm`'s `factor.scores(ltmmod)` function.

Comment: This problem I encountered seemed to have something to do with the amount of respondents. I started calibrating when there were not enough respondents yet. Your solution works fine!

Answer (score 0):

The package eRm (Mair& Hatzinger) is also dealing with missing values. But eRm only estimates unidimensional models http://erm.r-forge.r-project.org/